# DialogFragment with custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, dialogfragment

I'm trying to create a DialogFragment that shows a dialog with a custom ListView inside.

```
public class MultiSelectDialogCustom extends DialogFragment {


    ListView mLocationList;
    private ArrayList<String> mOfficeListItems = new ArrayList<String>();


    public static MultiSelectDialogCustom newInstance(int title) {
        MultiSelectDialogCustom dialog = new MultiSelectDialogCustom();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Collections.addAll(mOfficeListItems, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.offices)); 
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choice_list, container,
                true);

        mLocationList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.location_criteria_list);

        final FunctionListArrayAdapter adapter = new FunctionListArrayAdapter(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mOfficeListItems);
        mLocationList.setAdapter(adapter);

        getDialog().setTitle(getArguments().getInt("title"));

        return v;
    }


}
```

When calling it from a fragment :

```
MultiSelectDialogCustom dialogFrag = MultiSelectDialogCustom_.newInstance(R.string.dialog_title);
dialogFrag.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

It only shows a blank dialog with the title... why my isn't my list displayed?

Comment: For me it was as easy as setting my listView's height from 0dp to 200dp. Didn't need an AlertDialog.Builder or override onCreateDialog.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using `onCreateView` you should be overriding `onCreateDialog` and inside of it, it'll look something like:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Collections.addAll(mOfficeListItems, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.offices)); 
    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_choice_list, null);

    mLocationList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.location_criteria_list);

    final FunctionListArrayAdapter adapter = new FunctionListArrayAdapter(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mOfficeListItems);
    mLocationList.setAdapter(adapter);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle(getArguments().getInt("title")).setView(v);

    return builder.create();
}
```

This quote from the `DialogFragment` [documentation page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) describes what you're trying to do:

> Implementations should override this class and implement `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` to supply the content of the dialog. Alternatively, they can override `onCreateDialog(Bundle)` to create an entirely custom dialog, such as an `AlertDialog`, with its own content.

In your case, it seems like `onCreateDialog` is the way to go since you want to do a custom inner view.

Comment: I think you are right about using onCreateDialog. But the code you supplied can't work since onCreateDialog wants a Dialog for return not a View...

Comment: @TrtG Oops yep, I messed up my edit of adding the full code :) Couple small notes about the builder: 1. you can change it (setTitle() returns the builder) 2. It's bad to do setTitle(int) because that will get parsed as a string resource, not an actual cast of the int as text, so you should explicitly make it a string like I did.

Comment: Just one thing. The change you made on builder.setTitle() is not working, it's printing the int itfself as a string. So you get a title like "256542". I took off the empty string concatenation and it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing something very small but important. Are you missing `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your adapter?

"Once you have added the new item to the adapter you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` so that the `listview` refreshes itself with the new set of data found in the adapter."

Comment: I've added it but it didn't change anything. I don't think this can be the problem because I use the same adapter in regular fragments and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

what I forgot was:

```
view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

after I added that the code worked

Comment: There isn't any variable called `view` or `adapter` in the code in the question, so it isn't clear where you are putting this code.