# DialogFragment not keeping parameter

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I want to put a custom listView inside a dialogFragment (just like in this post [DialogFragment with custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356038/dialogfragment-with-custom-listview)) but I can not find out why my very simple way to do doesn't work. I want to pass my list as a parameter, since it is not composed of Strings and can evolve. So here is my DialogFragment :

```
public class ExternalInfoSelectorFragment extends DialogFragment{

    ListView choiceList;
    private ArrayList<ExternalObjectPoulpe> poulpeGet;

    public ExternalInfoSelectorFragment newInstance(int title, ArrayList<ExternalObjectPoulpe> liste){
        ExternalInfoSelectorFragment dialog = new ExternalInfoSelectorFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("Notes", title);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        this.poulpeGet = liste;
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_poulpe_choice, null, false);
        choiceList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListePoulpe);
        externalObjectPoulpeAdapter adapter = new externalObjectPoulpeAdapter(getActivity(),poulpeGet, null);
        choiceList.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
```

And the way I'm calling it :

```
    ajoutNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ExternalInfoSelectorFragment frag = new ExternalInfoSelectorFragment();
            frag = frag.newInstance(R.id.AddNote, getAllNotesTest());
            frag.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
        }
    });
```

The thing is that I got a null pointer exception on my list, even tho my list is not empty. What is wrong with that? I'm very unfamiliar with dialog Fragments and Fragments in general so if you could provide me a sample or give me some details it would be great.

The log as asked :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main   Process: com.example.rlaville.gestionsav, PID: 500
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:486)at     com.example.rlaville.gestionsav.Vues.ExternalInfoSelectorFragment.onCreateView(ExternalInfoSelectorFragment.java:47)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It is not the way, how things should be passed to Fragment(as DialogFragment is sitll Fragment): 'this.poulpeGet = liste;' in newInstance. This, what I propose here is using gson to 'serialize' your list and adding it to args Bundle, and then using standard ways to retrieve data in onCreate (from savedInstance or getArguments) and then again deserialize it with Gson

Comment: I've tried with arguments, but can't fin a way to convert my serializable back into an arraylist when I want to use it... this is why i've tried this way

Comment: in newInstance, try this:
args.putString("data", gson.toJson(liste)

then in onCreate:
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ExternalObjectPoulpe>>()
                {
                }.getType();
poulpeGet = gson.fromJson(getArguments().getString("data"), type);


Of course it is still good to implement onSaveInstance + make it null safety. Also I think, that I don't have to add, that "data" name of argument should be done as constatnt somewhere