# Error when showing custom listView in a dialogfragment (Xamarin Android)

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to show a custom listview in a dialog fragment with Xamarin for an Android application. 
The dialog fragment shows a spinner and a custom listview. The listview show in each row 5 information, like name, surname, age... This information is stored in a object called testResults. 
In my dialog fragment, I populate a list and pass this to the curstom adapter with the hope to see the information displayed. 
This works when I call it from a normal activity (i.e. when the listview is not is a dialog fragment) but not when I want to show it inside a dialog. 
Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

**The DialogFragment**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

   var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_createAccount, container, false);
   Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.NoTitle);

   listResults = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listResults);
   listAdapter = new MyListViewAdapter(Activity, testResults, Resource.Layout.listview_row);

   listResults.Adapter = listAdapter;

   spinAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
   spinAdapter.Add("Male");
   spinAdapter.Add("Female");

   spin.Adapter = spinAdapter;

   spin.ItemSelected += Spin_ItemSelected;

   return view;
}

private void Spin_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
  // populate the List<testResults> (which is empty at the beginning)
}
```

**The adapter:**

```
class MyListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<testResults>
{
    public List<testResults> mItems;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mRowLayout;
    private string[] mAlternatingColors;

    // Default constructor
    public MyListViewAdapter(Context context, List<testResults> items, int rowLayout)
    {
        mItems = items;
        mContext = context;
        mRowLayout = rowLayout;
        mAlternatingColors = new string[] { "#F2F2F2", "#00bfff" };
    }

    // Tells how many rows are in the dataset
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return mItems.Count; }
    }

    // Return a row identifier
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    // Return the data associated with a particular row
    public override testResults this[int position]
    {
        get { return mItems[position]; }
    }

    // Return a view for each row
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_row, null, false);
        }

        row.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor(mAlternatingColors[position % mAlternatingColors.Length]));

        TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Name);
        txtName.Text = mItems[position].Name;

        TextView txtSurname = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Surname);
        txtSurname.Text = mItems[position].Surname;

        TextView txtAge = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Age);
        txtAge.Text = mItems[position].Age;

        return row;
    }

    private Color GetColorFromInteger(int color)
    {
        return Color.Rgb(Color.GetRedComponent(color), Color.GetGreenComponent(color), Color.GetBlueComponent(color));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Please use [`OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)) instead of `OnCreateView`.

---

Like @Kasra Rahjerdi have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356038/dialogfragment-with-custom-listview), you need override `OnCreateDialog` method, do like this:

```
public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var view = Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_createAccount,null);
    Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.NoTitle);

    listResults = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listResults);
    listAdapter = new MyListViewAdapter(Activity, testResults, Resource.Layout.listview_row);

    listResults.Adapter = listAdapter;

    spinAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
    spinAdapter.Add("Male");
    spinAdapter.Add("Female");

    spin.Adapter = spinAdapter;

    spin.ItemSelected += Spin_ItemSelected;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);

    builder.SetView(view);
    return builder.Create();
}
```

In the `OnCreateDialog` you need `AlertDialog` to achieve your goal.